# Python, breaking up Strings

Tags: python, string

I need to make a program in which the user inputs a word and I need to do something to each individual letter in that word. They cannot enter it one letter at a time just one word.

I.E. someone enters "test" how can I make my program know that it is a four letter word and how to break it up, like make my program make four variables each variable set to a different letter. It should also be able to work with bigger and smaller words.

Could I use a for statement? Something like For letter ste that letter to a variable, but what is it was like a 20 character letter how would the program get all the variable names and such?

Comment: Can you explain the exact use case where you want to do this? I mean, why would you like to have 20 variables for 20 length string at all?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a data structure like a list, but it's worth noting a string is also an iterable, so it's probably not needed.

Comment: a WORD is a string/list of Characters. You can parse a word like parsing a list. What is the problem ??

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from some reading on basic data structure types in programming to give you an idea of how data can be stored and used in nice ways. Khan Academy has some video lectures on Python like https://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science/v/python-lists which might help (disclaimer: I've only flicked through the video - it may not be as good as I think).

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> s = 'four'
>>> l = list(s)
>>> l
['f', 'o', 'u', 'r']
>>>
```

Addendum:

Even though that's (apparently) what you think you wanted, it's probably not necessary because it's possible for a string to hold virtually any size of a word -- so a single string variable like`s`above should be good enough for your program verses trying to create a bunch of separately named variables for each character. For one thing, it would be difficult to write the rest of the program because you wouldn't to know what valid variable names to use.

The reason it's OK not to have separate variable for each character is because a single string can have any number of characters in it as well as be empty. Python's built-in`len()`function will return a count of the number of letters in a string if applied to one, so the result of`len(s)`in the above would be`4`.

Any character in a string can be randomly accessed by indexing it with an integer between`0`and`len(s)-1`inside of square brackets, so to reference the third character you would use`s[2]`. It's useful to think of the index as the *offset* or the character from the beginning of the string.

Even so, in Python using indexing is often *not* needed because you can also iteratively process each character in a string in a`for`loop without using them as shown in this simple example:

```
num_vowels = 0
for ch in s:
    if ch in 'aeiou':
        num_vowels += 1
print 'there are', num_vowels, 'vowel(s) in the string', s
```

Python also has many other facilities and built-ins that further help when processing strings (and in fact could simplify the above example), which you'll eventually learn as you become more familiar with the language and its many libraries.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate a string, it returns the individual characters like

```
for c in thestring:
    print(c)
```

You can use this to put the letters into a list if you really need to, which will retain its order but `list(string)` is a better choice for that (be aware that unordered types like dict or set do not guarantee any order).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do any of those; In Python, you can access characters of a string using square brackets:

```
>>> word = "word"
>>> print(word[0])
w
>>> print(word[3])
d
>>> print(len(word))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to assign each letter to a separate variable. Then you'd be writing the rest of your program without even being able to know how many variables you have defined! That's an even worse problem than dealing with the whole string at once.

What you instead want to do is have just *one* variable holding the string, but you can refer to individual characters in it with indexing. Say the string is in `s`, then `s[0]` is the first character, `s[1]` is the second character, etc. And you can find out how far up the numbers go by checking `len(s) - 1` (because the indexes start at 0, a length 1 string has maximum index 0, a length 2 string has maximum index 1, etc).

That's much more manageable than figuring out how to generate `len(s)` variable names, assign them all to a piece of the string, and then know which variables you need to reference.

Strings are immutable though, so you can't *assign* to `s[1]` to change the 2nd character. If you need to do that you can instead create a list with e.g. `l = list(s)`. Then `l[1]` is the second character, and you can assign `l[1] = something` to change the element in the list. Then when you're done you can get a new string out with `s_new = ''.join(l)` (`join` builds a string by joining together a sequence of strings passed as its argument, using the string it was invoked on to the left as a separator between each of the elements in the sequence; in this case we're joining a list of single-character strings using the empty string as a separator, so we just get all the single-character strings joined into a single string).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'test'   
counter = 0   
while counter < len(x): 
    print x[counter]  # you can change this to do whatever you want to with x[counter]
    counter += 1
```

Comment: There is no real reason to use a `while i < len(x)` here - it just introduces more complicated code instead of using the tools Python provides to do this in a nicer way.